# endpoint not reachable when request is too large (30 Mb +)

Tags: asp.net, wcf, model-view-controller, file-upload, web-config

I'm trying to upload files via MVC and WCF.

My web.config on MVC project is configured to recive large files.

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFile" closeTimeout="00:30:00"
      openTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom" />
```

The problem occurs when I call my WCF. The endpoint is right on MVC project and the web.config on WCF has this binding:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="FileUploadServiceBinding"
             transferMode="Streamed"
             messageEncoding="Mtom"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             receiveTimeout="00:30:00"
             openTimeout="00:30:00"
             closeTimeout="00:30:00"
             sendTimeout="00:30:00">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="100"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

I'm sending files of 25Mb and it's working, but when I try to upload files of 30Mb or more, my project can't reach the service, throwing this error message:

"There was no listening endpoint at http://localhost:55010/FileService.svc able to accept the message." This is usually caused by an incorrect SOAP address or action. Get more details. "

Thank you!

Comment: Did you also set the server's [MaxBufferSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.maxbuffersize(v=vs.95).aspx)?  The default is only 64k. Any chance there is a timeout occuring? Any chance there is a network node in between (e.g. an inbound proxy server or gateway) that can't handle the message size?

Comment: Server's MaxBufferSize its right too. The timeout is 30 minutes. I've found the solution. It's the server's httpRunTime. Now the property MaxRequestLength is "2147483647" and its working. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem on server's web.config with the following line:

```
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" enableVersionHeader="false" maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="1600" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2147483647" />
```

Now my problem is the System.OutOfMemoryException when i'm trying to copy my stream to a memorystream, but it's out of this post escope.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting your service in IIS Express, or IIS, chances are the default value for the `maxAllowedContentLength` of the Request Filtering module is getting in the way (it's 30000000 by default).

Try increasing it by adding something like the following in your web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering >
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
    <requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: The problem was the property maxRequestLength on tag httpRuntime that was not configured. Now it's setted to 2147483647 and the problem with web.config is fixed. Thank you.